# Making an absolute div hollow?

Tags: html, css

Currently my dilemma is that I have a div positioned absolute sitting on top of all my code (it has a sliding animation) however I now cannot access the content behind the top div..

This has the animation, but no links or buttons will work: http://oxygenrad.io/index.php

This is without the animated div and has the working links and buttons: http://oxygenrad.io/index-2.php

The div that's causing all of my issues is the following:

```
<div class="reveal open">
</div>
```

I understand that I could just destroy the div after :XX seconds, but ideally I was wondering if there was a better solution? All I want to be able to do is click through the div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pointer-events: none;` on your div as follows :

```
.opened {
  background: url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px 660px, url(http://uploadir.com/u/9btuxs9t) 0px -735px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states, click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is visible.

For IE11 you can use :

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_transparent.png', sizingMethod='scale');
background: none !important;
```

Comment: @JamesLawson As myself and Mir have suggested, this will only work in the latest version of IE. You should use `z-index:0;` instead for cross-browser compatibility (see my answer below).

Comment: @JamieBarker you have a point, but for his current code your solution would ruin his effect..

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `pointer-events: none` (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) page for details). But be aware that it [will not work with IE < 11](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `pointer-events: none;` as some have suggested, just add `z-index:0;` to your `.opened` class. Works in all legacy browsers, whereas `pointer-events` does not.

Comment: My only issue with this is that I have `.reveal` as `z-index:2;` to make sure that it sits on top of the rest. Adding `z-index:0;` repositions it behind some of the content. I might be able to work this into the original stylesheet css, however I don't have access to my raw copy right now, the only version to hand is obfuscated.

Comment: @JamesLawson Either way, your current answer won't work on browsers that many people still use. You're going to need to set `z-index:0;` to that container after it's animation is finished, or just remove the element entirely if it's no longer needed.